# The range of the value returned by InputStream read function

Tags: java, int, byte, inputstream, javadoc

I have the following code that reads bytes from a file and print it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("myFile")) {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[3];
        while (is.read(bytes) != -1) {
            System.out.println("bytes = " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the content of myFile:

```
AAABBB|||ùùù
```

Here is the output:

```
bytes = [65, 65, 65]
bytes = [66, 66, 66]
bytes = [124, 124, 124]
bytes = [-7, -7, -7]
```

My question is, since the range value of a byte is – 128 to 127, it's normal to see negative value in the output. Nonetheless, the javadoc of the **InputStream.read()** method says

> The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255

Isn't it a bit ambiguous? How the int (0 to 255) is mapped to the byte (– 128 to 127)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are calling `int read(byte b[])` not `int read()`. you can check it by:

```
    try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("myFile")) {
        int i;
        while (true) {
            i = is.read();
            if (i == -1) break;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

and Second, Maybe you will curious about the size of bytes,  because `ùùù` are unicode characters, every unicode character needs 2 bytes in `Java`